# Missing CFBundleIconName in Xcode app release

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm trying to release an app using Xcode. Archiving and uploading the binary goes well without any issue. However the build doesn't appears in App Store Connect and I get an email

> Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, >"LycCalculator" 1.2 (1). Please correct the following issues, then upload >again.
>
> ITMS-90713: Missing Info.plist value - A value for the Info.plist key >'CFBundleIconName' is missing in the bundle 'kim.LycCalculator'. Apps >built with iOS 11 or later SDK must supply app >icons in an asset catalog >and must also provide a value for this Info.plist key.

I've tried a lot of things fix this problem. I have all the app icons, app icon source is the app icon but I can't add 'CFBundleIconName' to my Info.plist so I only added icon name.
So here some screenshots of what I have right now:
[app icons and launch images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f42o9.png) , [app icons in assets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgKrQ.png) , [info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MofEU.png)

Any suggestion of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: check your actual icon file names. maybe its have been writing non-english alphabet like korean.

Comment: Hi Irina, did you resolve that issue? I've the same right now with Xcode 13 building a capacitor app...